# R- using unlist to convert the output to a data frame

Tags: r, rvest

When I run the following piece of code

```
library(rvest)

elec<-read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenyan_general_election,_1988")
res<-elec%>% html_nodes("table.wikitable")%>%html_table(fill=TRUE)
res
```

I get a list of 1 within which there seems to be the dataframe.

```
  str(res)
  List of 1
  $ :'data.frame':       5 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Party: chr [1:5] "Kenya African National Union" "Invalid/blank votes" 
   "Total" "Registered voters/turnout" ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get it as a data frame instead of a data frame within a list(at least that's how it seems to be currently)

Comment: You can assign it `df <- res[[1]]`

Comment: Or you can use `html_node` (without the "s" on the end) since in this case, there is only one `table.wikitable` on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html_table` takes either a `node` or a `node set` (list of nodes) as an input. You're providing a `node set` of length one by using `html_nodes`, use `html_node` instead:

```
res<-elec%>% html_node("table.wikitable")%>%html_table(fill=TRUE)
```